# Golang MongoDB Driver sort

Tags: mongodb, go

How to query find using golang mongodb driver?

I try this one :

```
db.Collection("products").Find(nil, bson.M{}, &options.FindOptions{Sort: "-price"})
```

But I got this error :

> cannot transform type string to a BSON Document: WriteString can only write while positioned on a Element or Value but is positioned on a TopLevel

I don't know what to pass to Sort variable becuase it is an interface{}.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try the below code

```
findOptions := options.Find()
// Sort by `price` field descending
findOptions.SetSort(bson.D{{"price", -1}})


db.Collection("products").Find(nil, bson.D{}, findOptions)
```

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't pass ‍‍`bson.D` to options(It caused error).
but this code worked for me:

```
    queryOptions := options.FindOneOptions{}
    
    queryOptions.SetSort(bson.D{{"priority", -1}, {"last_error_time", 1}})

    sResult := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), queryFilter, &queryOptions)
```

Comment: bson.M and bson.D is very similar but in this context you have to use bson.D because it maintains the order of arguments.

You cant fix the errors like this:

queryOptions.SetSort(bson.D{{Key: "priority", Value: -1}, {Key: "last_error_time", Value: 1}})

Comment: @Denis Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

A few notes I've come across trying to solve a related problem:

- If trying to sort by multiple fields be sure to use bson.D rather
  than bson.M because bson.M doesn't preserve order.
- If trying to programmatically build up multiple sort fields, try
  appending bson.E to a bson.D
- As dassum did, pass bson.M{} for an empty filter as recommended by
  the [mongo documentation](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Find)

Applied:

```
sort := bson.D{}
for _, example := examples {
    sort = append(sort, bson.E{example, 1})
}

findOptions.SetSort(sort)
db.Collection("products").Find(nil, bson.D{}, findOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another point to note, make sure that mapping of field names are correct. In my case i was trying to sort a field `createdAt` but after realized my mongodb field is mapped as `createdat`.

```
queryOptions.SetSort(bson.D{{"createdat", -1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
findOptions := options.Find()
// Sort by `price` field descending
findOptions.SetSort(bson.M{"price": -1})


db.Collection("products").Find(nil, bson.D{}, findOptions)
```

This helped me to fix my code.This problem is due to the version of go that you are using.